# Fluent NHibernate SQLException with no existing columns inside table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm reimplementing some methods which accesses a database objects. I rebuilded a table in database dropping 4 columns. Than I removed Fluent NHibernate mapping, table objects class and try to create new object in database. While I'm calling `.Save()` method from `ISession()` there is an exception:

`{NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Uzytkownik][SQL: INSERT INTO dbo.[uzytkownik] (aktywne, haslo, login, dostep) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'imie'.
Invalid column name 'nazwisko'.
Invalid column name 'telefon'.
Invalid column name 'adres_email'.
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction)`

Dropped columns are 'imie', 'nazwisko', 'telefon', 'adres_email'. I looked for any of that in source and cannot find it any more. This is my mapping class:

```
using System;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Mappings
{
    public class UzytkownikMapping : ClassMap<Uzytkownik>
    {
        public UzytkownikMapping()
        {
            Table("`uzytkownik`");
            Schema("dbo");
            Id(x => x.IdUzytkownik, "id_uzytkownik").GeneratedBy.Native();
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Map(x => x.Aktywne, "aktywne");
            Map(x => x.Haslo, "haslo");
            Map(x => x.Login, "login");
            Map(x => x.Uprawnienia, "dostep");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Aktywas)
                .ChildKeyColumn("id_aktywa")
                .ParentKeyColumn("id_uzytkownik")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("aktywa_role")
                .Fetch.Select()
                .AsSet();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Rolas)
                .ChildKeyColumn("id_rola")
                .ParentKeyColumn("id_uzytkownik")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("aktywa_role")
                .Fetch.Select()
                .AsSet();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.RoleSystems)
                .ChildKeyColumn("id_role_system")
            .ParentKeyColumn("id_uzytkownik")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("role_system_uzytkownik")
                .Fetch.Select()
                .AsSet();
            HasMany(x => x.UzytkownikAtrybutys)
                .KeyColumn("id_uzytkownik")
                .Fetch.Select()
                .AsSet()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        }
    }
}
```

And `Uzytkownik` class:

```
using System;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

namespace Model
{
[Serializable]
public partial class Uzytkownik
{
    public Uzytkownik()
    {
        Aktywas = new HashedSet<Aktywa>();
        Rolas = new HashedSet<Rola>();
        RoleSystems = new HashedSet<RoleSystem>();
        UzytkownikAtrybutys = new HashedSet<UzytkownikAtrybuty>();
    }

    public virtual int Uprawnienia
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual string Haslo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual int IdUzytkownik
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual string Login
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual ISet<Aktywa> Aktywas
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual ISet<Rola> Rolas
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual ISet<RoleSystem> RoleSystems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual ISet<UzytkownikAtrybuty> UzytkownikAtrybutys
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual bool Aktywne { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        return Equals(obj as Uzytkownik);
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Uzytkownik obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        if (Equals(Aktywne, obj.Aktywne) == false) return false;
        if (Equals(Haslo, obj.Haslo) == false) return false;
        if (Equals(IdUzytkownik, obj.IdUzytkownik) == false) return false;
        if (Equals(Login, obj.Login) == false) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int result = 1;

        result = (result * 397) ^ Aktywne.GetHashCode();
        result = (result * 397) ^ (Haslo != null ? Haslo.GetHashCode() : 0);
        result = (result * 397) ^ IdUzytkownik.GetHashCode();
        result = (result * 397) ^ (Login != null ? Login.GetHashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Any idea where I could make a mistake? Or maybe NHibernate could have an additional mapping file?

@Edit
Mapping into configuration:

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(connectionString)
            .ExposeConfiguration(   c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add<UzytkownikMapping>())
NHibernateCfg = configuration.BuildConfiguration();
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure(NHibernateCfg).BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession().Save(NewUser);
```

Comment: did you rebuild the whole project?(made the dll's after changing the mapping) It maybe silly but still trying to help. Also where is the in. Also check project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your configuration was not rebuild. Check this article for more details: [Optimizing application startup time with Fluent NHibernate and uNhAddIns](http://entron.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/optimizing-application-startup-time-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-unhaddins/)

An extract:

> The important piece of code was the FluentlyConfigure() method...
>
> ...Now this is still in `Foo.Data`, so if this changes the configuration object won’t get rebuilt. I need to move it out to `Foo.Data.Mappings` so that if I change anything there, the configuration does get rebuilt.

So, you may have configuration in not rebuild project, while mappings are placed elsewhere...

Comment: OK, I tried to make some rebuilded configuration but it still informs me that it has additional columns. I've made something like in first post after @Edit.

Comment: Seems ok to me... the point is, that from experience we know that: 1) you have changed the mapping in code 2) NHibernate is still provided with the old mapping. It is hard to guess what all could be wrong... But I would now suggest: clean solution, assure that no old dll remains. Assure that your code is in place and rebuild. That must for sure provide NHibernate with the latest mapping. Other words, this is the issue. The old mapping. I am sure